# "Found dwarf version '4', this reader only handles version 2 information" при компиляции

Tags: c++, компиляция

При компиляции программы на C++ в Dev-C++ возникает ошибка:

> "found dwarf version '4', this reader only handles version 2
>   information"

Что она означает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dwarf - это формат отладочной информации. Видимо, в библиотеках, которые вы линкуете, он такой (версии 4), который эта древность (Dev-C++ в смысле) уже не поддерживает.